# Variables shown as "function () { [native code] }" in mail sent using google apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to send out mails with individual variables (name and dates).
Instead of the variables, the mail shows "function () { [native code] }" at the place where I expected the variable.
My code for the sendMail function is:

```
  function sendMailAN(guest, date) {
      var emailAddress = 'sample@gmail.com'
      var message = 'You created an offer for guest ' + guest + '. The guest will be arriving on ' + date
      var title = 'Offer for ' + guest + ' created'
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, title, message)
  }
```

Does anybody have an idea what the problem here is and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

The variables guest and date that the function gets when called in the script are shown as "function () { [native code] }" in the mail.

Comment: Which variable?

Comment: What are the arguments being passed to the function?

Answer (score 1):

`guest` and `date` are functions and not strings. Therefore when they are converted to strings you get

> "function () { [native code] }" in the mail.

Did you mean `guest()` instead of `guest`?